# Is minimum perimeter of rectangle with integer area $k\times a$ monotonic in $k$ for every $a$?

Tags: geometry, number-theory

Let $p(k)$ represent the minimum perimeter of a rectangle with **integer width and height** with area 
$a\times k$, where $a$ and $k$ are both positive integers. Is $p$ monotonically non-decreasing in $k$ for every $a$?

It seems to be true. Examples:

For $a=7$: $p(1)=16, p(2)=18, p(3)=20, p(4)=22, ...$.

For $a=8$: $p(1)=12, p(2)=16, p(3)=20, p(4)=24, ...$.

Here's what I've tried: Let $f(z)$ denote the largest integer factor (not necessarily prime) of $z$ such that $f(z) \leq \sqrt{a}$. It's easy to show that $p(k) = 2(f(ka) + ka/f(ka))$. If I could show that $f(ka)<f(k'a)$ whenever $k'>k$, then the proof would be easy. But it turns out that the latter assertion is false (counterexample: set $a=49,k=4,k'=5$)

Comment: Do you want to require the sides of the rectangle to be integers?

Comment: Yes, thanks; just clarified that in edited problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $a = 1$.  $p(5) = 12 > p(6) = 10$.

Or for $a = 2$, $p(7) = 18 > p(8) = 16$.

Comment: I'm also curious about the particular case: Is $p(k)>p(2)$ for all $k>2$ for every $a$? Do you have any suggestions for what kinds of literature might be relevant for me to read about this?

Answer (score 1):

If $a=1$, then $p(5) = 12$, but $p(6)=10$.

More generally, if $a=1$, then for any prime $n>3$,

$$p(n) = 2(n+1) = 2n + 2$$
$$p(n+1) \le 2\left(2 + \frac{n+1}{2}\right)=n + 5$$

hence $p(n+1) < p(n)$.