# Minimal perimeter for a rectangle with integer sides

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For given area how to find out what is minimal perimeter of rectangle with integer sides? It is easy for square area or prime area.

Examples:

- minimal perimeter for rectangle with area `= 10000` is `400` (because it is rectangle `100x100`)
- for area `= 1000` is `130` (`40x25`)
- for area `= 5` is `12` (`5x1`)

Is there any general rule?

I read this:
[Is minimum perimeter of rectangle with integer area $k\times a$ monotonic in $k$ for every $a$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2190301/is-minimum-perimeter-of-rectangle-with-integer-area-k-times-a-monotonic-in-k)

but it doesn't help

Comment: $a b= n $ such that $a+b$ is minimal, so the trivial answer is to choose $a,b$ that factors $n$ and the nearest to $\sqrt{n}$, but if you are asking to find them then its equivalent for **factoring** $n$ which is a very very hard problem in math and CS.

Comment: So in general I need factor `n` by all numbers from `1` to `√n` and choose biggest factor?

Comment: true, otherwise i would take the perimeter you found and factor $n$ which will compromise online security.